# How to format scientific E notation into human readable numbers? (numbers larger than BigDecimal)

Tags: java, numbers, decimal, bigdecimal

I'm trying to create a number class which can hold values from `4.9E-324e-1.7976931348623157E308` to `1.7976931348623157E308e1.7976931348623157E308` in both signs. (yes, the exponent is also a double)

My number class is in base 2.

I have all the arithmetic working, but I'm having trouble trying to display it as a string in the format `...#####.#####...`.

This is what I've come up with.

```
@Nonnull
    public String toReadableString(@Nonnull MathContext context) {
        try {
            final BigDecimal mantissa = BigDecimal.valueOf(y);
            final BigDecimal exponentiation = BigDecimal.valueOf(2).pow((int) x, context);
            // The above line throws an ArithmeticException if magnitude(x) > 999999999
            // This is defined in BigDecimal, and I can't change the limit

            final BigDecimal result = mantissa.multiply(exponentiation);

            return result.toPlainString();
        } catch (final ArithmeticException e) {
            return "OUT_OF_DISPLAYABLE_RANGE";
        }
    }
```

I've tried searching for other methods of converting base 2 to base 10, but every method I could find involves actually calculating the value as a `double`, which would obviously not work for most values of this number class.

#### Summary

I need a function `toReadableString() : String` which can reliably convert base 2 scientific notation in the form of `2^double * double` for an arbitrary `n` number of decimal points.

Any help would be great, even if it's not a complete solution.

For reference, here's the structure of my number class.

```
// This extends Vector2 to use all the features provided by the vector class
public class RealNumber extends Vector2 implements Comparable<RealNumber> {
    public RealNumber(double val);
    public RealNumber(double exponent, double mantissa);

    public final double exponent();
    public final double mantissa();

    // Code ommitted

    public String toReadableString(MathContext context); // Body defined above
}
```

**I know this is very impractical and abstract. I personally like that kind of stuff, and this is a purely personal project which I'm doing for fun.**

I've tried:

- Converting `exponent` and `mantissa` to `BigDecimal` to calculate the value (BigDecimal.pow(int) causes a problem)
- The current approach
- Just using `double` (of course it doesn't work)
- Iterating through each digit and adding the value to a `BigDecimal` (maybe there was an error in my code, but didn't work)

Comment: It doesn't really help that you don't say what this mysterious "problem" is

Comment: @g00se BigDecimal#pow(int) doesn't allow the use of the full integer range. And even if it did, it still wouldb't be enough coverage for by double exponent, even if I gave up the accuracy of double.

Comment: Raising 2 to the xth power can be done with `new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(x))`.  I’m not sure if that helps.